# JavaScript / jQuery: possible to 'automate' switch statement through for loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, scroll, switch-statement

**SOLUTION**

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
            var y = $(this).scrollTop();
            for (var i = 0; i < offset.length; i++)
                {
                    if (y < offset[i].bottom) {
                        $("#catSelect option:selected").removeAttr("selected");
                        $("#catSelect option[value=#"+offset[i].id+"]").attr("selected", "selected");
                        break;
                    }
                }
        });
```

Thank you for your help guys!

**PROBLEM**

I am a beginner at JavaScript and jQuery, so I hope some kind soul can help me out.
Below is a snippet of a code that executes just fine... but as it is pretty repetitive, I am trying to come up with some code to help me 'automate' all these conditions within the switch statement instead of manually specifying it (if that makes sense). I'm going with a 'for' loop but no results as of yet.

A nudge in the right direction, please? Thank you :)

~ preliminary code ~

```
var offset = [];
        $(".cat").each(function() {
            var top =  $(this).offset().top;
            var bottom = top + $(this).outerHeight();
            var id = $(this).attr("id");
            offset.push({"top": top, "bottom": bottom, "id": id });
            $(document.body).append(offset.length);
        });
```

~ the code it's all about ~

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var y = $(this).scrollTop();

        switch (true) {
            case (y < offset[0].bottom):
                $("#catSelect option:selected").removeAttr("selected");
                $("#catSelect option[value=#"+offset[0].id+"]").attr("selected", "selected");
                break;
            case (y < offset[1].bottom):
                $("#catSelect option:selected").removeAttr("selected");
                $("#catSelect option[value=#"+offset[1].id+"]").attr("selected", "selected");
                break;
            case (y < offset[2].bottom):
                $("#catSelect option:selected").removeAttr("selected");
                $("#catSelect option[value=#"+offset[2].id+"]").attr("selected", "selected");
                break;
            }

        });
```

Comment: This is wrong: `i > offset.length` It should be `i < offset.length`, so it evaluates as `0 < 3`, `1 < 3`, `2 < 3`, stop. Your loop never runs, as the first evaluation is `0 > 3`, which is false.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it's only the array index that differs in the different cases:

```
for (var i = 0; i < offset.length; i++) {
  if (y < offset[i].bottom) {
    $("#catSelect option:selected").removeAttr("selected");
    $("#catSelect option[value=#"+offset[i].id+"]").attr("selected", "selected");
    break;
  }
```

Comment: Why use the name `i` instead of `index`?  `i` is the worst variable name ever, looking much like `1`, `l`, and `i`.

Comment: I am just curious: does the OPs answer cause a jump to the first statement that evaluates true? I imagine the inner workings of javascript cause each one to be checked until a true one is found

Comment: thanks for the quick reply! I've tried this earlier (although I think you meant "i > offset.length"). It doesn't work! Hm.

Comment: @AKG - It's `i < offset.length`. Otherwise, it would never run, eg, first loop would evaluate `0 > 3`.

Comment: @JaredFarrish. I just tried i < offset.length - it just keeps evaluating the last statement to be true upon scrolling

Comment: @Hogan: The variable name `i` is by far the most commonly used for loop counters, followed closely by `j` and `k`. This is an old tradition coming from Fortran, where those variables automatically were integers because of their names. Even if the variable names themselves are not great, it's a pattern that is widely recognised among programmers, so it's the best choise if you want a short variable name for a loop counter.

Comment: @AKG - I would believe that's an error in your `if` logic; the iterator, though, should be `i < array.length`, otherwise it never runs.

Comment: @AKG: Oh, so more than one condition can match, and you want only the first found match to be used. Use a `break` to get out of the loop. I added it above.

Comment: Such a silly oversight on my part. Thank you guys! @JaredFarrish

Comment: @Guffa The question was rhetorical.  There are many Fortran constructs we don't use now.  Please join me in not using `i` to mean `index` or `integer` or `iterator`.

Comment: @Hogan - I see windmills. And wouldn't `i` in most cases semantically shortcut `iterator`? `i` is a common enough construct; personally, I don't think it's similar to `l` or `1` at all, and of course is literally similar to `i`.

Comment: @Hogan: It's not here because it comes from Fortran, it's here because it still works. There are a lot of actual anti-patterns out there, some of them even dangerous, that I rather want to kill off.

Answer (score 4):

Yours is a remarkable approach! I had never considered `switch(true)` :)

You could try this and see if it works for you:

```
for (var i = 0; i<=2; i++)
{
    if (y < offset[i].bottom) {
        $("#catSelect option:selected").removeAttr("selected");
        $("#catSelect option[value=#"+offset[i].id+"]").attr("selected", "selected");
    }
}
```

Comment: Why use the name `i` instead of `index`?  `i` is the worst variable name ever, looking much like `1`, `l`, and `i`.